# Clearing .appendTo when element isn't being hovered over

Tags: jquery, hover, appendto

Alright so I used .appendTo to beat an issue of overflow:hidden so my entire tooltip would show outside the containing div. However, it locks the tooltip in place after the item was hovered over. How do I go about clearing the .appendTo to hide the tooltip.

```
$(this).hover(function(){
var pos = $.extend({}, $(this).offset(), {width: this.offsetWidth, height:        this.offsetHeight});
$(this).children('.browse-tip').css({top: -40, left: pos.left - pos.width / 2});
$(this).children('.browse-tip').show();
$(this).children('.browse-tip').appendTo('#browse_wrap');
},function() {
$(this).children('.browse-tip').hide();
});
```

Comment: Would be helpful to see the rest of the context and what's happening with #browse_wrap. Perhaps a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole structure of the thing is making your work challenging. I recommend having an independent element that you can float around the page toggling when needed, and just putting the relevant info into it before showing:

```
<div id="popup"></div>

<style>
#popup {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999999;
    width: 220px;
    height: 200px;
}

#popup .browse-tip {
    display: block;
}
</style>

<script>
$(this).hoverIntent(function(){
    var pos = $.extend({}, $(this).offset(), {width: this.offsetWidth, height: this.offsetHeight});
    $(this).children('.browse-tip').clone().appendTo("#popup");
    $("#popup").css({top: pos.top-40, left: pos.left - pos.width / 2});
    $("#popup").show();
    return true;
},function() {
    $("#popup").hide().children().remove();
    return false;
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pMSRp/

Comment: You just made me very happy. Thank you sir.